# Parse Query containing comma ","

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a form where it's possible to have a name with multiple values (e.g: `<input name="name1" type="text">` and there's is another input with the same name `name1`). And when I want to get the data in a handler, I use the method `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString()` and then I put it in a `var nameValue` so when I want to get the value, I do `nameValue["name1"]`. The problem is that when I get the value of `name1` I get `"name1_value1,name1_value2"` with the comma as separator, so I need to split it to get `"name1_value1""name1_value2"` separately, but what if `name1_value1` contained actually a comma `(,)` then there's the problem. 
What I did is transform `context.Request.Params` into string, then replace all the commas (encoded to `%2c` in params) with `;;;` and replace them again when I finished the splitting but I'm not sure this would work properly because maybe there is another special character which contains `%2c`

Comment: Pleas give me a sample of the query string...

Comment: "noInventaire=&dateMiseEnService=&etat=1&utilisateur=1&constructeurCPU=Intel&referenceCPU=Core+i5+3210M+2.45Ghz&socketCPU=1151&constructeurRAM=Kingston&constructeurRAM=Kingston&referenceRAM=Kingston+021EF2%2c+PC12800&referenceRAM=Kingston+021EF2%2c+PC12800&capaciteRAM=4&capaciteRAM=4&DDRRAM=DDR3&DDRRAM=DDR3&constructeurDrive=HITACHI&referenceDrive=HGST+HTS7210&capaciteDrive=1000&typeDrive=HDD"

Comment: I would have answered your question about comas, but unfortunately it sent me to sleep :D

Comment: you can answer it when you'll wake up then :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said `nameValue["name1"]` will join the result by a comma and that is what you don't want. So it is better to forget the `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString()` and parse the query string by on your own.

```
string queryString = url.Split('?')[1];
string[] qsArray = queryString.Split('&');
var name1 = qsArray.ToList().Where(A => A.StartsWith('name1'));
```

Now you have your values totally separated.

Comment: But in this case, I need to handle all the special characters from the query, right?

Comment: Could you please more explain? What you mean when you say: *I need to handle all the special characters*?

Comment: because, I do $("#myForm").serialize() when I send it from the page to the server, where " " becomes "+" and "," becomes "%2c" etc... So I need to handle those

Comment: You can decode your url bofore split by `HttpUtility.UrlDecode`

Comment: Or, i think I have an idea ... get the values as you did and then use the HttpUtility.ParseQueryString() when all are separated